# metabase.xml doesn't exist

Tags: iis-6, windows-xp

I have a Windows XP running under Virtual PC, but I think that this doesn't matter since IIS6 theoretically should behave the same as on usual Windows XP.
The problem is that Metabase.xml doesn't exist. Why? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mixed that up: WinXP has IIS6, not IIS5.1.